# Как преобразовать двумерный массив в одномерный?

Tags: java

Дан на вход программы двумерный массив. Значения из него нужно записать в одномерный массив, по массиву пройтись "змейкой" и вывести на экран.

В моем коде выдает ошибку переполнения массива:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class SnakeArray {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SnakeArray snakeArray = new SnakeArray();
        snakeArray.toSnakeArray(new int[][]{{1, 2}, {4, 5}});
    }

    private void toSnakeArray(int[][] largeArray) {

        String[] smallArray = new String[largeArray[0].length + largeArray[1].length];

        for (int i = 0; i < smallArray.length; i++) {
            for (int j=0;j<smallArray.length;j++) {
            smallArray[i] = String.valueOf(largeArray[i][j]);
            }
            }

            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(smallArray));
        }
    }


  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 2 
SnakeArray.toSnakeArray(SnakeArray.java:20) 
SnakeArray.main(SnakeArray.java:11)
```

Comment: Приведите точный текст ошибки

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 2
 SnakeArray.toSnakeArray(SnakeArray.java:20)
 SnakeArray.main(SnakeArray.java:11)

Comment: Под вопросом кнопка "править", используйте ее

Comment: вы идёте по длинне smallArray  в цикле а не по largeArray

Comment: да, но на вход в качестве размерности я передаю размерность большого массива

Comment: private void toSnakeArray(int[][] largeArray) {
    String[] smallArray = new String[largeArray[0].length + largeArray[1].length];int index = 0;for (int i = 0; i < largeArray.length; i++) {
            for (int j=0;j<largeArray[i].length;j++) {
            smallArray[index++] = String.valueOf(largeArray[i][j]);
            }
            }

            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(smallArray));
        }
    }

нужно что то типа такого

Comment: "Змейкой" - это как? По строкам? По столбцам? Справа налево? Слева направо? Змейка по-разному ползает ))) А лучше нарисуйте ожидаемый результат))

Comment: здесь имеет ввиду  [0][0] ->[1][0] -> [1][1] -> [0][1]

Comment: Размерность одномерного массива должна быть равна произведению размерностей двумерного. Как вам верно заметили, в циклах нужно перебирать значения 0 <= i < largeArray.length и 0 <= j < largeArray[i].length. Для номера элемента одномерного массива нужен отдельный счётчик (или вычислять его по i и j). В зависимости от чётности i, вы можете выбирать начальное значение j и в теле цикла менять его как j++ или j-- (при этом в круглых скобках не менять).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Старайтесь писать более универсальные методы. Что если массив состоит не из интов или матрица лохматая? Хотелось бы не переписывать код каждый раз. Кроме того, массивы, безусловно, имеют свои преимущества, однако в большинстве случаев использовать коллекции на много проще, особенно с учетом того, что ArrayList в себе по сути инкапсулирует этот самый массив, соответственно, получит массив в нужный момент не составит труда. И последнее... Зачастую проще использовать циклы без индексов либо стримы просто потому, что такой код читается проще и меньше шансов допустить ошибку.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class SnakeArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SnakeArray snakeArray = new SnakeArray();
        List<Integer> result = snakeArray.toSnakeArray(new Integer[][]{{1, 2}, {4, 5}});
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result.toArray()));
    }

    private <T> List<T> toSnakeArray(T[][] array) {
        final List<T> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (T[] arrays : array) result.addAll(Arrays.asList(arrays));
        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Но здесь задание конкретное.

Comment: @Delembech вам абстрактного задания никто никогда и не поставит. задание всегда будет конкретное, а вывести из этого абстракции - и есть ваша задача. в противном случае на выходе процедурная реализация , жуткое дублирование кода дублирование кода и т.д. по списку